# EasyPHP 16.1.1 installation causes PHP warnings

Tags: php, easyphp

Installed EasyPHP 16.1.1 on Windows 10 but when launching, I get the following errors:

[core:warn] [pid 10808:tid 580] AH00098: pid file C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1/eds-binaries/httpserver/apache2418vc11x86x160806141849/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php5624vc11x86x160810035427\php.ini on line 877 in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gd: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mbstring: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysql: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysqli: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php5624vc11x86x160810035427\ext\php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php5624vc11x86x160810035427\ext\php_pgsql.dll' - The operating system cannot run %1.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sockets: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

and some other errors.

I'm assuming this is because I have older versions of EasyPHP/PHP/MySQL on my drive but was not able to figure out how to properly uninstall them. What is going on and what needs to be done to get the new version to work properly?

Comment: nuke EVERYTHING to do with the old version, basically The `API=` business is proof-positive that it's finding your old install and trying to use files/dlls from that, and not the new version.

Comment: That was my guess but was not able to find any documentation on how to properly uninstall older versions.